# Is there a better way than double parsing the string?

Tags: python, regex

I'm parsing an iptables' log file seeking for the source IPs. To do so, I'm using two instances of `re.findall`, one for finding "SRC=x.x.x.x" and the other for actually getting the IP.

```
for line in iptables:
    src = re.findall('SRC=\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}', line)
    ip = re.findall('\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}', src)
```

Is there a better way to achieve the same result? That is, just getting the SRC IP.

For what I want to do right now it really doesn't matter, but I'd like to know whether are there better methods of achieving the same for future development.

Comment: Can't you put a group `(...)` around the IP?

Comment: @tobias_k I don't understand what do you mean. What's the difference between what I wrote and `(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})`?

Comment: The parentheses capture the value if found so it can be used later.

Comment: but it would capture every IP right? that is both SRC and DST.

Comment: If you found `SRC=x.x.x.x`, you can just remove `SRC=` from `src`, although I prefer @tobias_k answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put the IP-part into a group, i.e. inside parentheses. This way, you can `search` a match and get the `group` inside that match.

```
>>> line = "SRC=127.0.0.1"
>>> m = re.search(r'SRC=(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})', line)
>>> m.group(0)
'SRC=127.0.0.1'
>>> m.group(1)
'127.0.0.1'
```

Here, `group(0)` is the entire match, `group(1)` the part enclosed in the first set of `()`, and so on.

Comment: alright, in 7 minutes answer accepted. Just another question, what's the 'r' used for?

Comment: mmm btw, I'm noticing that I don't need to use `m.group(0)` and `m.group(1)`, just printing `m` the IP is shown.

Comment: The `r` makes Python not interpret the backslashes in the string as escape characters. You do not really need it here, as `\d` would not be a valid escape sequence anyway, so Python ignores it.

Comment: @yzT that indicates that it is a raw string. It means you don't need to escape '\' and slash sequences are not escaped, so `r'\n'` is not a newline. https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals

Comment: Then you were probably still using `findall` instead of `search`. `findall` works, too, but `search` gives you a "Match" object from which you can, e.g. also get the spans of the match (its position in the string), if you need it.

Comment: yeah, just noticed the findall